# Getting current jar file's name

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I have this code which on the dev-environment return the information.
But when I run from the jar the code doesn't follow how it should.

The name of the jar is hardcoded and would like to get it's name, because versions vary.

```
private static String getManifestUrlForClass(Class<?> cl) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

        URL url = cl.getResource(cl.getSimpleName() + ".class");
        String s = url.toString();

        System.out.println("URL Path: " + url.getPath());
        System.out.println("URL File: " + url.getFile());

        String path = MYCLASS.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        String revisionNumber = "";
        String decodedPath = "";

        JarFile jarfile = null;


         try {
        decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8").replace("classes", "");

         try {
        jarfile = new JarFile(decodedPath + "MYJAR-ver.si.on.jar"); 
         } catch (IOException e1) {

         System.out.println("or Path to file cannot decode...");
         e1.printStackTrace();
         }

        Manifest manifestFromJar = jarfile.getManifest(); //

        System.out.println("Manifest from " + jarfile.getName().toString() + " = "
                + manifestFromJar.getMainAttributes().getValue("Revision-Number").toString()); 

        revisionNumber = manifestFromJar.getMainAttributes().getValue("Revision-Number").toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println(url.getFile().toString() + "is not jar");// TODO Auto-generated catch block
         System.out.println("or Path to file cannot decode...");
         e.printStackTrace();
         }

        return revisionNumber;

    }
```

MYJAR will always be the same but the |ver.si.on| will most likely vary and hardcoding the name isn't a best practice.

What I want to do? 
1. Get the MYJAR-ver.si.on.jar's location no matter where it is located
2. Use the location to access it's Manifest
3. Use the Manifest to extract revision number
4. Show the revision number in the ui

I'm new yet to java and don't understand it pretty well. I've read something about using "rsrc:" to get to the jar, or something similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40680501/6756124 .

Comment: So what are you actually getting when you run it from the jar?

Comment: Error file not found exception. It would be helpful to see what this accesses while running from the jar.

Comment: The stacktrace will tell you what File it was trying to find. Could you post that as well